# gtk+: how to refresh canvas immediately (closed)

Tags: canvas, gtk, refresh

Followed is a layout in `gtk+`.

```
+----------------------------+------+------+------+
|                            |Page 1|Page 2|Page 3|
|                            +------+------+------+
|                            |                    |
|                            |                    |
|     Canvas area            |                    |
|                            |                    |
|                            |                    |
|                            |                    |
|                            |                    |
|                            |                    |
+------------------+---------+                    |
|                  | button  |                    |
|                  +---------+                    |
|                            |                    |
|                            |                    |
|                            |                    |
|                            |                    |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
```

-> "Canvas area" and "button" on the left are in a vertical box. "Page 1~3" on the right are the pages of a notebook in another vertical box.

-> "Canvas area" on the left is created by `gtk_drawing_area_new` and connected with signal `expose-event`.

-> In "page 3", there is a "Canvas area", which is created similarly like above.

-> Every time when I press "button", the "Canvas area" on the left is refreshed at once.

The problem is

-> If Page 3 is the **current** page, when pressing "button", the "Canvas area" in the page 3 won't refresh until I switch to another page, e.g., Page 1 or Page 2, then switch back to Page 3. It seemed that the signal `expose-event` won't emit if always staying "Page 3".

-> Is it possible to refresh the "Canvas area" in Page 3 when Page 3 is the `current` page, just like what "Canvas area" on the left refreshes immediately when pressing "button"?

-> I haved tried `gdk_threads_enter`, `gdk_threads_leave`, but it didn't work.

Please help. Thank you.

---

**Followed is a small example. It works well, I mean the problem mentioned above won't come up. The problem is in the function "button_pressed" where I missed "gdk_invalidate_region (g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "right_canvas"));" in my application.**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int num, if_draw = 0;

void gdk_invalidate_region (GtkWidget *obj)
{
  GdkRegion *region;

  region = gdk_drawable_get_visible_region(obj->window);
  gdk_window_invalidate_region(obj->window, region, TRUE);
  gdk_region_destroy (region);
  gtk_widget_queue_draw(obj);
  /* gdk_window_process_updates(obj->window, TRUE); */
}

void num_changed (GtkWidget *box, GtkWidget *window)
{
  num = gtk_option_menu_get_history((GtkOptionMenu *)box) + 1;
  if_draw = 0;
  gdk_invalidate_region (g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "left_canvas"));
  gdk_invalidate_region (g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "right_canvas"));
}

gboolean draw_expose_left (GtkWidget *canvas, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer user_data)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  cr = gdk_cairo_create (canvas->window);
  if(if_draw)
  {
    int i;

    cairo_set_line_width (cr, 0.7);
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
      printf("i=%d\n", i);
      cairo_move_to(cr, 50, (i + 1) * 50);
      cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 150, 0);
      cairo_stroke(cr);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
    cairo_set_font_size(cr, 0.35);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 5, canvas->allocation.height / 2);
    cairo_show_text(cr, "Press button \"Press..\" to update!!");
  }
  cairo_destroy (cr);

  return FALSE;
}

gboolean draw_expose_right (GtkWidget *canvas, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer user_data)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  cr = gdk_cairo_create (canvas->window);
  if(if_draw)
  {
    int i;

    cairo_set_line_width (cr, 0.7);
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
      printf("i=%d\n", i);
      cairo_move_to(cr, (i + 1) * 50, 50);
      cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 0, 100);
      cairo_stroke(cr);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
    cairo_set_font_size(cr, 0.35);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 5, canvas->allocation.height / 2);
    cairo_show_text(cr, "Press button \"Press..\" to update!!");
  }
  cairo_destroy (cr);

  return FALSE;
}

void button_pressed (GtkWidget *button, GtkWidget *widget)
{
  gdk_invalidate_region (g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "left_canvas"));
  gdk_invalidate_region (g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "right_canvas"));
  if_draw = 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window, *main_box, *box, *hbox, *entry, *menu, *menu_item;
  GtkWidget *notebook, *label;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  /* gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200); */
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  main_box = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), main_box);
  gtk_widget_show(main_box);

  /***** left **********/
  box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_box), box, FALSE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_widget_show(box);

  entry = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(entry, 400, 200);
  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "left_canvas", entry);
  gtk_widget_show(entry);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(draw_expose_left), window);

  hbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), hbox, FALSE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_widget_show(hbox);

  entry = gtk_label_new("Num: ");
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_widget_show(entry);

  entry = gtk_option_menu_new();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(entry, 40, -1);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_widget_show(entry);

  menu = gtk_menu_new();
  menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("1");
  gtk_widget_show(menu_item);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menu_item);
  menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("2");
  gtk_widget_show(menu_item);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menu_item);
  menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("3");
  gtk_widget_show(menu_item);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menu_item);
  gtk_option_menu_set_menu(GTK_OPTION_MENU(entry), menu);
  gtk_option_menu_set_history((GtkOptionMenu *)entry, 1);
  num = 2;
  gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(entry), "changed", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(num_changed), window);

  entry = gtk_button_new_with_label("Press..");
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(entry), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(button_pressed), window);
  gtk_widget_show(entry);
  /*********************/

  /***** right *********/
  box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_box), box, FALSE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_widget_show(box);

  notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
  gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), GTK_POS_TOP);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), notebook, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  /* g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(notebook), "switch-page", G_CALLBACK(qqaa_show_page_status_ACC_platform), window); */
  gtk_widget_show(notebook);

  entry = gtk_label_new("ONE");
  label = gtk_label_new("Page 1");
  gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), entry, label);

  entry = gtk_label_new("TWO");
  label = gtk_label_new("Page 2");
  gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), entry, label);

  entry = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(entry, 400, 200);
  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "right_canvas", entry);
  gtk_widget_show(entry);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(draw_expose_right), window);
  label = gtk_label_new("Page 3");
  gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), entry, label);
  /*********************/

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you using `gtk2` or `gtk3`, `expose-event` got superseded by `draw` (look that up again)

Comment: Can you add a minimal example, this smells like a signal handler returning `TRUE`, or a wrong signal source connection, but for more than wild guessing some code is required.

Comment: @drahnr: A small example is added in the post. It didn't show the problem I mentioned. So, the expose-event signal is blocked by somewhere else I still didn't find.

Comment: you got 2 options, add more code from your application to the demo until it breaks, or remove code from your aplication code until works, and post the working vs the not working code here. A minimal demo _not_ showing the issue is not really helpful

Comment: @drahnr: I found the problem. Please read the post. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Answer the question yourself, that is the way this is supposed to be done if you found the solution yourself. Do not modify the question itself (except to supply additional information)